# I have a mesh, how to find its deepest point that could fit a sphere?

Tags: math, polygon, surface, minimization

So I have a 3D polygon based mesh surface (2.5D). I want to find its deepest point (minimum) that could fit a sphere of radius r. How to do such thing not utilizing physics engine?

Comment: Linear programming could be a suitable algorithm with the sphere approximated by a suitable mesh itself.